# Identify Chinese board game

Tags: identify-this-game

I came across this Chinese board game. It has a cloth board and 25 black pieces and 25 red pieces with Chinese characters on them. 
Can anyone identify it and link to its rules?
Thanks.

[image: Chinese board game]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an abstract strategy game known as [Luzhanqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzhanqi) ("Land Battle Chess").